# Specflow filter tests by tag without vstest.console (Xunit.runner)

Tags: c#, xunit, specflow

I feel like this should be incredibly simple but I am using xunit.runner to run my specflow tests. I have added smoke and regression tags. I know I can run via the vstest console and use something like

```
dotnet test --filter <Smoke>
```

I can't see an option to filter via the xunit.runner.json can't see anything to suggest where I could filter from. I know SpecRunner allows you to do it

Cheers

Comment: You should be able to specify filter in the .runsettings file or in the .json file that you specify for xunit.runner.json. 
If you have a .runsettings file, you can add a <TestRunParameters> section with all the filter options. 
If you have a .json file, you can add a "filter" section with all the filter options. 
If you are using a .runsettings file that already has a <TestRunParameters> section, you can add the filter options under the existing <TestRunParameters> section.

Comment: @AmirrezaHashemi, can you add your comment as an answer?

Comment: Thanks for the response, i had tried "filter" in the json file but i get "Property name is not allowed by the schema"

Answer (score 0):

After being pointed in the right direction by @Amirreza Hashemi

i created a .runsettings file and added

```
<RunConfiguration>
    <TestCaseFilter>Category=smoke</TestCaseFilter>
</RunConfiguration>
```